# Any example for gantt chart using d3.js in react.js either with d3.js or react.js approach?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, gantt-chart

I want to build gantt chart using d3.js in my react.js app. But both manipulate DOM. So,there are 3 ways https://frontendcharts.com/react-d3-integrate/ to go with this. I will like to go with first approach i.e D3 approach. It'll be highly appreciated if I get a basic example implemented as I have to showcase it to my senior.

I tried below code but it gives error 'gantt' is not exported from 'd3' (imported as 'd3'). One thing more is that how to add this gantt chart to SVG.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';


let tasks = [
    { "startDate": new Date("Sun Dec 09 01:36:45 EST 2012"), "endDate": new Date("Sun Dec 09 02:36:45 EST 2012"), "taskName": "E Job", "status": "RUNNING" },
    { "startDate": new Date("Sun Dec 09 04:56:32 EST 2012"), "endDate": new Date("Sun Dec 09 06:35:47 EST 2012"), "taskName": "A Job", "status": "RUNNING" },
    { "startDate": new Date("Sun Dec 09 06:29:53 EST 2012"), "endDate": new Date("Sun Dec 09 06:34:04 EST 2012"), "taskName": "D Job", "status": "RUNNING" },
    { "startDate": new Date("Sun Dec 09 05:35:21 EST 2012"), "endDate": new Date("Sun Dec 09 06:21:22 EST 2012"), "taskName": "P Job", "status": "RUNNING" },
    { "startDate": new Date("Sun Dec 09 05:00:06 EST 2012"), "endDate": new Date("Sun Dec 09 05:05:07 EST 2012"), "taskName": "D Job", "status": "RUNNING" },
    { "startDate": new Date("Sun Dec 09 03:46:59 EST 2012"), "endDate": new Date("Sun Dec 09 04:54:19 EST 2012"), "taskName": "P Job", "status": "RUNNING" },
    { "startDate": new Date("Sun Dec 09 04:02:45 EST 2012"), "endDate": new Date("Sun Dec 09 04:48:56 EST 2012"), "taskName": "N Job", "status": "RUNNING" },
    { "startDate": new Date("Sun Dec 09 03:27:35 EST 2012"), "endDate": new Date("Sun Dec 09 03:58:43 EST 2012"), "taskName": "E Job", "status": "SUCCEEDED" },
    { "startDate": new Date("Sun Dec 09 01:40:11 EST 2012"), "endDate": new Date("Sun Dec 09 03:26:35 EST 2012"), "taskName": "A Job", "status": "SUCCEEDED" }
];

let taskStatus = {
    "SUCCEEDED" : "bar",
    "FAILED" : "bar-failed",
    "RUNNING" : "bar-running",
    "KILLED" : "bar-killed"
};

let taskNames = [ "D Job", "P Job", "E Job", "A Job", "N Job" ];

class Chart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tasks: tasks,
            taskStatus: taskStatus,
            taskNames: taskNames,
            format: "%H:%M",
        }
    }

    drawChart = () => {
        let gantt = d3.gantt().taskTypes(this.state.taskNames).taskStatus(this.state.taskStatus).tickFormat(this.state.format);
        return gantt(this.state.tasks);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.drawChart()}
                {/* <svg width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height} ref={e1 => this.svgE1 = e1}></svg> */}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Chart;
```

I just want a basic example of gantt chart using d3.js in react.js

Comment: `d3.gantt` is not in the base `d3` library. There is probably an import statement that you are missing that adds a gantt functionality.

Comment: May be, but I tried every single thing from imports to degrading the d3 package to version 3 e.t.c

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `d3.gantt()` is an external library called [`Gantt-Chart`](http://dk8996.github.io/Gantt-Chart/), so in addition to `d3` library it needs to be imported as well.

And last but no least, make sure to install `d3` version `V3`, for example: `npm i d3@3.5.12` since `d3-gantt-chart` is compatible with `v3` version.

Once `d3` and `d3-gantt-chart` packages are installed, the chart component could be implemented like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import * as d3 from "d3";
import "d3-gantt-chart";

class GanttChart extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.drawChart();
  }

  drawChart() {
    const { tasks, taskTypes, taskStatus, tickFormat } = this.props;
    var gantt = window.d3
      .gantt()
      .taskTypes(taskTypes)
      .taskStatus(taskStatus)
      .tickFormat(tickFormat);
    gantt(tasks);
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default GanttChart;
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dm5ujx) for your reference (adapted from [this original example](http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5449641))

Comment: I have already tried all these scenarios and imports yesterday after exhaustive googling session of 4-5 hrs. But still the error is same, I could have implemented in pure d3.js as my aim was to use d3.js to build a gantt chart but I don't want to write hundred lines of code. Infact no good examples are there for gantt chart in d3.js which can be easily integrated in react. But yeah I got to learn little bit of d3.js and in the end I settled down with react-google-charts and reat-gantt-timeline , both are superb npm packages as they provide callbacks for interactivity.

Comment: @DeepankarSingh, i agree, but have you seen the [provided demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dm5ujx) which demonstrates how to integrate Gantt-Chart into React app?

Comment: I tried this example only, but didn't tried  this Window.d3 = d3; syntax. Now there is no error in console earlier which was d3.gantt() is not a function. But nothing is rendered.